# Build Error -- Attempting to watch missing directory

Tags: ember.js

I’m trying to setup an existing Ember application on my local PC.
I have installed all the necessary packages.

But when I try to run the application, it gives me build error.

[image]

Edit:

Error Log:

```
=================================================================================

ENV Summary:

  TIME: Wed May 13 2020 23:37:22 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
  TITLE: ember
  ARGV:
  - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
  - C:\Users\upervaiz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\bin\ember
  - serve
  EXEC_PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
  TMPDIR: C:\Users\upervaiz\AppData\Local\Temp
  SHELL: null
  PATH:
  - C
  - \ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C
  - \Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C
  - \Python37\Scripts\;C
  - \Python37\;C
  - \Program Files\Python37\Scripts\;C
  - \Program Files\Python37\;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C
  - \Windows\system32;C
  - \Windows;C
  - \Windows\System32\Wbem;C
  - \Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C
  - \Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C
  - \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C
  - \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C
  - \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C
  - \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C
  - \Python27\;C
  - \Python27\Scripts;C
  - \Program Files\PuTTY\;C
  - \Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C
  - \Program Files\Git;"C
  - \Windows;C
  - \Windows\System32;C
  - \Python27";C
  - \Program Files\helm\windows-amd64;C
  - \Program Files\IBM\Cloud\bin;C
  - \xampp\php;C
  - \ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C
  - \WINDOWS\system32;C
  - \WINDOWS;C
  - \WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C
  - \WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C
  - \WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C
  - \AIRSDK\bin;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\gnupg\bin;C
  - \Program Files\nodejs\;C
  - \Program Files\Git\cmd;C
  - \Program Files\Git\bin;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C
  - \Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\server;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Roaming\npm
  PLATFORM: win32 x64
  FREEMEM: 6010388480
  TOTALMEM: 17054658560
  UPTIME: 969
  LOADAVG: 0,0,0
  CPUS:
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz - 2496
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz - 2496
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz - 2496
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz - 2496
  ENDIANNESS: LE
  VERSIONS:
  - ares: 1.16.0
  - brotli: 1.0.7
  - cldr: 36.0
  - http_parser: 2.9.3
  - icu: 65.1
  - llhttp: 2.0.4
  - modules: 72
  - napi: 5
  - nghttp2: 1.40.0
  - node: 12.16.3
  - openssl: 1.1.1g
  - tz: 2019c
  - unicode: 12.1
  - uv: 1.34.2
  - v8: 7.8.279.23-node.35
  - zlib: 1.2.11

ERROR Summary:

  - broccoliBuilderErrorStack: Error: Attempting to watch missing directory: 
    at Watcher_addWatchDir [as addWatchDir] (D:\projects\neb\front\compliance-app\node_modules\ember-cli-broccoli-sane-watcher\index.js:142:11)
    at D:\projects\neb\front\compliance-app\node_modules\broccoli-builder\lib\builder.js:136:35
    at tryCatch (D:\projects\neb\front\compliance-app\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:525:12)
    at invokeCallback (D:\projects\neb\front\compliance-app\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:538:13)
    at D:\projects\neb\front\compliance-app\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:606:14
    at flush (D:\projects\neb\front\compliance-app\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:2415:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
  - codeFrame: Attempting to watch missing directory: 
  - errorMessage: Build Canceled: Broccoli Builder ran into an error with `Funnel` plugin. 
Attempting to watch missing directory: 
  - errorType: Build Error
  - location:
    - column: [undefined]
    - file: [undefined]
    - line: [undefined]
    - treeDir: [undefined]
  - message: Build Canceled: Broccoli Builder ran into an error with `Funnel` plugin. 
Attempting to watch missing directory: 
  - name: Error
  - nodeAnnotation: Funnel
  - nodeName: Funnel
  - originalErrorMessage: Attempting to watch missing directory: 
  - stack: Error: Attempting to watch missing directory: 
    at Watcher_addWatchDir [as addWatchDir] (D:\projects\neb\front\compliance-app\node_modules\ember-cli-broccoli-sane-watcher\index.js:142:11)
    at D:\projects\neb\front\compliance-app\node_modules\broccoli-builder\lib\builder.js:136:35
    at tryCatch (D:\projects\neb\front\compliance-app\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:525:12)
    at invokeCallback (D:\projects\neb\front\compliance-app\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:538:13)
    at D:\projects\neb\front\compliance-app\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:606:14
    at flush (D:\projects\neb\front\compliance-app\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:2415:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)

=================================================================================
```

Comment: same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61760106/ember-js-attempting-to-watch-missing-directory

Comment: which ember / ember-cli version do you use?

Comment: @AndreyStukalin it's 3.18.0

Comment: Can you debug node processes? I don't have a Windows environment; otherwise, I would debug this error on `node_modules\ember-cli-broccoli-sane-watcher\index.js:142:11`, there's a `dir` argument get passed in, see if it's reasonable and to further dig in that why this `dir` has been considered not exists.